# Usar 2 versiones de angular en 2 proyectos distintos en mi maquina (v6 y v9)

Tags: angular, angular6, angular9

Actualmente tengo un proyecto desarrollado en angular 6, ahora tengo un nuevo proyecto y quiero usar angular 9.

De que forma puedo hacer esta actualización de angular sin afectar el proyecto que ya esta funcionando.

Comment: Sigue esta guia para hacer una actualizacion del proyecto https://update.angular.io/#6.0:9.0

Answer (score 0):

Cada proyecto tendra un package.json donde se especifica la versión de angular que usas en cada uno de ellos. Siempre y cuando los tengas en carpetas diferentes no deberías tener ningún problema.

Edit:

You could use NVM (https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) which allows you to work with different global modules in each Node version.

You could use locally installed ng `node_modules/.bin/ng`

You could use npx `npx @angular/cli@6 serve`

You could have `ng` in package.json (scripts) seciton and run it with npm `npm run ng -- <options>`

Or you could just use Docker and run with docker instead

Comment: La version de `ng` es lo que perjudica a los proyectos anteriores.